# how to delete a row in a gridview using delete button outside the grid?

Tags: c#-2.0

i have a grid in which there are various records. On my form i have a Update and Delete button outside the grid. there are different textbox. when i selected a row in a grid its value appear in these textbox from where i can update these value. thats work fine for me. Now i want to delete the selected row?
    i dont want to delete a record using delete button in the grid. i want when i select a row and press a delete button then the selected row should delete from grid as well from database.

Comment: It is a Windows app. or WebApp.?

Answer (score 0):

I guess if you have already done the update part then you can easily delete the selected row. Just call a delete function, instead of the update one, and then call the DataBind() function of the GridView.

Comment: i have updated the records by using textbox. but i dont understand how to delete the selected row by single click button. some one say use viewstate or session to store the id feild and then use these to delete the record. i want to know how i can use viewstate property to delete a selected record in a grid.

Comment: What I'm saying is that as you have updated the selected record then you know exactly which record has been selected (this might be by its id) then knowing this exact record and instead of calling the updateRecord(id, newText) just call deleteRecord(id) where these two functions are functions you probably defined to access your data source.