# how to delete a row from the gridview by using a button outside the gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

This seems like a repeated question but i'm not able to get my answer.

I have a grid view and I need to delete a particular row, when I click on a button outside the gridview.

```
 protected void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
            dtable = (DataTable)Session["data"];
            DataRow row = dtable.Rows[DataGV1.SelectedIndex];
            dtable.Rows.Remove(row);
            DataGV1.DataSource = dtable;
            DataGV1.DataBind();
            Session["data"] = dtable;
        }
```

The session variable has the previous state of datatable.

```
protected void DataGV1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView _gridView = (GridView)sender;

        // Get the selected index 
         _selectedIndex = int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
     }
```

Gridview controls

```
        onselectedindexchanged="DataGV1_SelectedIndexChanged" 
        OnRowCommand="DataGV1_RowCommand" OnRowDeleting="DataGV1_RowDeleting"
        AutoGenerateSelectButton="False" DataKeyNames="Role,Last_name">
        <Columns>
            <asp:ButtonField DataTextField="last_name" HeaderText="Last_name" CommandName="SingleClick"
                SortExpression="last_name" Text="Button" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="role" HeaderText="role" SortExpression="role" />
             <asp:BoundField DataField="role" HeaderText="role"                      HeaderText="Frist_name" 
                 SortExpression="first_name" Text="First_name" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

This doesn't seem to work.
Can u please tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: Not sure but take a look at this http://forums.asp.net/t/1571655.aspx

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6070344/how-to-delete-a-row-in-a-gridview-using-delete-button-outside-the-grid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If *button* is outside the `GridView` then no need to handle `RowCommand` event (In fact it is inappropriate).

Suggestion:

You have to add a `TemplateField` column, drop the CheckBox control in ItemTemplate of TemplateField and write code in click handler of button to traverse the `GridView.Rows` collection, identify the selected row by reading value of `CheckBox` control and perform deletion action if that `CheckBox` is checked.

Demo DataSource (`List<T>`)

```
public class Item
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public static List<Item> Data()
    {
        List<Item> list = new List<Item>()
        {
                new Item(){ ID=11, Name="A"},
                new Item(){ ID=12, Name="B"},
                new Item(){ ID=13, Name="C"},
                new Item(){ ID=14, Name="D"},
                new Item(){ ID=15, Name="E"},
        };
        return list;
    }
}
```

Markup:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
   <Columns>
        <asp:ButtonField DataTextField="Name" HeaderText="Name" CommandName="SingleClick"
            SortExpression="last_name" Text="Button" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" SortExpression="ID" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:Button ID="btnDelete" runat="server" Text="Button" />
```

Code-behind (Page_Load)

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        Session["data"] = Item.Data();
        GridView1.DataSource = Session["data"];
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
    /*--- RowCommand handler ---*/
    GridView1.RowCommand += (sa, ea) =>
        {
            ViewState["RowIndex"] = ea.CommandArgument.ToString();
        };
    /*--- Delete button click handler ---*/
    btnDelete.Click += (sa, ea) =>
        {
            if (ViewState["RowIndex"] != null)
            {
                int index = int.Parse(ViewState["RowIndex"].ToString());
                List<Item> items = Session["data"] as List<Item>;
                items.RemoveAt(index);
                GridView1.DataSource = Session["data"];
                GridView1.DataBind();
                ViewState["RowIndex"] = null;
            }
        };
}
```

Comment: Thanks.. but i can't use a checkbox feild and i have to use a link button. Get the row in textboxes and then delete the row from the gridview aswell.

Comment: @user1488276 - Is there any *button* inside the GridView? Please post GridView markup and code that populate the GridView.

Comment: I have added the gridview controls

Answer (score 0):

You have to store the _selectedIndex in a ViewState, and then on delete button click you retrieve the _selectedIndex from the Viewstate and use that to delete the row from your dataset, and reload the grid.

```
protected void DataGV1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView _gridView = (GridView)sender;

        // Get the selected index 
         ViewState["SelIndex"] = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
     }

protected void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

  {
        if(ViewState["SelIndex"] == null)
            return;

        int selIndex = int.Parse(ViewState["SelIndex"]);

        dtable = (DataTable)Session["data"];
        DataRow row = dtable.Rows[selIndex ];
        dtable.Rows.Remove(row);
        DataGV1.DataSource = dtable;
        DataGV1.DataBind();
        Session["data"] = dtable;
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the reply.. but it still says Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Where did you get the error, try adding a try catch block, and show us a line nr

Comment: and always check if an object is not null

Answer (score 0):

take a look at these articles that would explain to delete a single/multiple rows from gridview.
http://technico.qnownow.com/2012/06/15/how-to-delete-multiple-rows-from-gridview-with-checkboxes/
http://technico.qnownow.com/2012/06/14/how-to-delete-a-row-from-gridview-with-client-side-confirmation/